# regex I am trying to find a comma at the end of a field which has no more fields after the comma

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a csv file comma separated file.  I have opened in Notepad++
I am using the Regular Expression option from the Search\Replace dialog.

E.g. data in the file

```
One,two,three
One,,three
One,two,
One,two,
```

In row 3 there is a comma at the last field with no space.
In row 4 there is a comma at the last field with a space.

I am trying to find the comma without the space at row 3

I have tried the following regular expression [,^\s$]|[,^[a-z$]]
It finds all of the commas.
It is interesting it even finds the comma without a space.  I thought ^\s means not include a space.  i.e. ^ means Not, \s means space.

I would just like to find the last field at the end of the record which has a comma without a space and without any characters.

What regeular expression do i use for this?
Thanks!

Comment: Downvoted because your question has no example, many spelling/ grammatical errors and no sample data.

Comment: I have added a sample data of what the file looks like.  Why the downvote?  I am new to Stackoverflow.

Comment: On the markup side, [you can type two spaces followed by a single newline character](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138776/how-to-do-a-single-newline-on-the-stack-overflow-website) to insert a single newline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a simple regex to check if a comma is not followed by a space at the end of a line.

```
,(?! )$
```

or if there are multiple spaces:

```
,(?! *)$
```

or if there is just any whitespace:

```
,(?!\s*)$
```

See screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just do that:

Find what: `,$`

Make sure that "Regular expression" is checked.